# WatchKit: Change app name in notification short look and long look?

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, watchkit, apple-watch

I'd like to display a different app name when I receive a notification on the Apple Watch, both in Short Look and in Long Look (in sash). Currently it is the same as the display name on the iPhone home screen.

I tried changing `CFBundleDisplayName` in the info.plist of both the WatchKit extension as well as the WatchKit app, but it didn't take effect on the real device (the sash title changed accordingly in iOS Simulator though).

Any idea how to change that?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the name when the notification privilege was granted will be remembered by iOS. Changing the app name later doesn't auto-update its name displayed in the notification.

Completely deleting and reinstalling the app worked at least for debugging purpose. Not sure if it is also a problem when updating apps from App Store.